# my phone stuck in Samsung logo

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, boot, hard-reset, samsung-galaxy-pocket

i am using Samsung galaxy pocket Android 4.0,but now struck on Samsung logo.i have done hard reset.but remains in same state.please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the phone in recovery. Remove your battery, put it back and then turn the phone on while holding down VOLUME UP and the HOME KEY. Navigate to Advanced, then clear cache and wipe dalvik. Try and restart. If it doesn't work, download Samsung Kies on your computer and try Emergency Firmwire Initialisation. If that still doesn't work... Format your phone from recovery.